# EF - Tries to add a new object instead of using existing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How come that when I try to add a case by using the bool method in CaseRepository.cs by assign a user to the case object to determine which user is the owner of the case (who created it?) - but when I try to assign it then it tries to add a new User object to the table too although it's an existing User I'm passing in as parameter?

In short: I'm trying to let a User create a case and assign that case to the user.

The reason for mapping MembershipUser to User object is to enable the EF (code first) to could use it for CRUD operations.

// CaseController.cs

```
[AuthWhere(AuthorizeRole.Developer)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateCaseViewModel model)
{
    var success = false;
    string message;

    User user = Mapper.Map<MembershipUser, User>(_membershipService.GetUserByUserName(User.Identity.Name));
    Case createCase = _caseService.CreateCase(model.Topic, model.Message);

    bool addCase = _caseService.AddCase(createCase, user);

    if(!addCase)
    {
        message = ControllerResources.CaseCreateFail;
    }
    else
    {
        success = true;
        message = ControllerResources.CaseCreateSuccess;
    }

    return Json(new
    {
        Success = success,
        Message = message,
        Partial = RenderPartialViewToString("List", GetCases)
    });
}
```

// RepositoryBase.cs

```
public class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public IDbContext Context { get; private set; }
    public IDbSet<T> ObjectSet { get; private set; }

    public RepositoryBase(IDbContext context)
    {
        Contract.Requires(context != null);

        Context = context;

        if (context != null)
        {
            ObjectSet = Context.CreateDbSet<T>();

            if (ObjectSet == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void Invariant()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(Context != null);
        Contract.Invariant(ObjectSet != null);
    }

    public IRepository<T> Add(T entity)
    {
        ObjectSet.Add(entity);
        return this;
    }

    public IRepository<T> SaveChanges()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return this;
    }
}
```

// CaseRepository.cs

```
public class CaseRepository : RepositoryBase<Case>, ICaseRepository
{
    public CaseRepository(IDbContext context)
            : base(context)
    {
        Contract.Requires(context != null);
    }

    public bool AddCase(Case @case, User user)
    {
        @case.User = user;

        ObjectSet.Add(@case);
        Context.SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar class described in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318820/ASP-NET-MVC-3-0-JqGrid-Unit-Of-Work-Repository-EF and in http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2012/03/04/new-pluralsight-course-building-asp-net-mvc-apps-with-ef-code-first-html5-and-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to make 2 of my mappings in the POCO classes virtual.

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying existing object, then you don't need to add to context again. Therefore just remove this line for updates:

ObjectSet.Add(@case);

You may need to consider to create two separate methods, Add and Update in CaseRepository class.

Comment: You might have got it wrong. What I'm trying to is to let a user create a Case and then add that case to that user.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize, I think the following is creating a new instance of user:

    User user = Mapper.Map<MembershipUser, User>(_membershipService.GetUserByUserName(User.Identity.Name));

The best would be to first retrieve the instance from datebase.

Comment: Yea.. Thats the whole idea - it takes a MembershipUser object and makes it a User object. The User object is then used to determine which user "owns" the create, however I'm using EF code first and the User objects is mapped to the aspnet_Users table where it should retrieve the data needed (which it does perfectly fine too?) - So the User object passed in is a MembershipUser retrieved from the aspnet_Users.. and therefore its not a new object, but just a User object.. Alright.. not sure any of that made sense. (updated the post)

Comment: May be it is attached with different context, in that case you need to attach to the current context.